# edit dataframe samples based on the differences between values in the column

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pandas dataframe:

Here is what I am trying to do:

1. Take the difference of values in the `start_time` column and find the indices with values `less than 0.05`
2. Remove those values from the `end_time` and `start_time` columns accounting for the difference

Let's take the example of dataframe below. The `start_time` column index 2 and 3 value have a difference of less than 0.05 (36.956 - 36.908667).

```
        peak_time  start_time   end_time
    1  30.691333   30.670667  30.710333
    2  36.918000   36.908667  36.932333
    3  37.001667   36.956000  37.039667
    4  37.210333   37.197333  37.306333
```

This is what I am trying to achieve. Remove the `start_time` from the 3rd column and `end_time` from the second column

```
        peak_time  start_time   end_time
    1  30.691333   30.670667  30.710333
    2  36.918000   36.908667  37.039667
    4  37.210333   37.197333  37.306333
```

Answer (score 1):

This **cannot** be achieved by a simple `shift`.
In addition, care should be taken when dealing with continuous `start_time` difference < 0.05.

1. Import pandas.

```py
import pandas as pd
```

2. Read data. Note that I add one additional row to the sample data above.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'peak_time': [30.691333, 36.918000, 37.001667, 37.1, 37.210333],
    'start_time': [30.670667, 36.908667, 36.956000, 36.96, 37.197333],
    'end_time': [30.710333, 36.932333, 37.039667, 37.1, 37.306333]
})
```

[image: Sample data]

3. Calculate the forward and backward difference of `start_time` column.

```py
df['start_time_diff1'] = abs(df['start_time'].diff(1))
df['start_time_diff-1'] = abs(df['start_time'].diff(-1))
```

[image: start time diff]

4. We can notice that ROW 2 has both differences less than 0.05, indicating that this row has to be first deleted.
   After deleting it, we need to record the `end_time` of the row about to be deleted in the next step.

```py
df2 = df[~(df['start_time_diff1'].lt(0.05) & df['start_time_diff-1'].lt(0.05))].copy()
df2['end_time_shift'] = df2['end_time'].shift(-1)
```

[image: delete both time < 0.05]

5. Then, we can use the simple diff to filter out ROW 3.

```py
df2 = df2[~df2['start_time_diff1'].lt(0.05)].copy()
```

[image: filter out ROW 3]

6. Finally, paste the `end_time` to the correct place.

```py
df2.loc[df2['start_time_diff-1'].lt(0.05), 'end_time'] = df2.loc[
    df2['start_time_diff-1'].lt(0.05), 'end_time_shift']
```

[image: past end time]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.shift()` to compare to prior row and take the difference to return rows where the difference is less than `.05` by creating a boolean mask `s`. Then, witrh `~` simply filter out those rows:

```
s = df['start_time'] - df.shift()['start_time']  < .05
df = df[~s]
df
Out[1]: 
   peak_time  start_time   end_time
1  30.691333   30.670667  30.710333
2  36.918000   36.908667  36.932333
4  37.210333   37.197333  37.306333
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use `.diff()`

```
df[~(df.start_time.diff()<0.05)]



peak_time  start_time   end_time
1  30.691333   30.670667  30.710333
2  36.918000   36.908667  36.932333
4  37.210333   37.197333  37.306333
```